# Problems copying music to Rhythmbox from ipod

Tags: music, rhythmbox, ipod

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and am working to setup Rhythmbox 3.0.2.  I plugged in my ipod nano and the device was properly detected and the music in the device appeared.  I then selected all the music from the device and attempted to copy it into my Music Library.

The ipod contains 908 songs (7.5 GB) and Rhythmbox reported it would take 2 days and 22 hours 40 Minutes, so I decided to let it run overnight.

The next morning I checked my music folder using Files and it contains 1,093 items (7.5 GB data).  The laptop may have suspended during the night due to a lack of activity (I since disabled suspending), but it looks like all the music was copied over from the device.

However, none of the music appears on the main screen when I click on the Music Library.  There's no progress indicator so I'm not sure if Rhythmbox is still processing the files.  The bottom of the screen still shows 2 days, 22 hours, 40 minutes (no countdown).  If I click play, Rhythmbox is able to play songs from the first folder located under the Music directory.

Is there a way to determine whether or not Rhythmbox is still processing the files?  Is there something I should select to refresh Rhythbox so it recognizes the newly imported songs.  What should I do to allow the music copied over from the device to appear on the screen when I select the Music Library?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert Rhythmbox user by any means, but when I set up all music on an external server, I selected "Import" in Rhythmbox and pointed to the server in the "Select a location containing music to add to your library" box.  That worked fine.

However, since you mention actually copying the music using Rhythmbox, your use case may be different, since I don't know how to do that.  I only pointed to previously stored music.